# pymongo query not returning results

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am having trouble with my query, i'm trying to use find contains query on a number of fields, here is my code. I would appreciate any help.

```
def loadContact(search):
    myQuery = {'username' : {'$ne' : session['username']},\
               '$and' : [{'$or' : [\
                     {'username' : '/.*' + search + '.*/i'},\
                     {'surname' : '/.*' + search + '.*/i'},\
                     {'firstName' : '/.*' + search + '.*/i'},\
                     {'email' : '/.*' + search + '.*/i'},\
                     {'company' : '/.*' + search + '.*/i'}]}]}
    cursor = db.users.find(myQuery)
    payload = []
    content = {}
    for doc in cursor:
        #this is mocked up code for this question so you can see more clearly
        content = {'username' : cursor[0], 'firstName' : cursor[1]}
        payload.append(content)

    return payload
```

Worth noting the loop does not iterate, the contents of the loop are not of great importance right now if it does not iterate.

Because i need concrete values for any string value, here are concrete values for any string:

```
session['username'] = "username" 
loadContact(): loadContact("string")
```

Comment: Is your code actually indented like that?

Comment: Yeh it is, I've just shorted the loop contents but it will be like that for all the fields

Comment: To get help you need to include the following: 1) value of `search` that you pass to the function 2) example of document that is not returned when you think it would be returned. 3) value of `session['username']`

Comment: Search is a string of text like "person" or "matt", username is "mfarrell1" or any kind if username

Comment: No, I mean one concrete example, that we can reproduce.

Comment: its just a string, stick any str in there, literally. however if you must have concrete values here.
setting session: session['username'] = "username" & calling loadContact(): loadContact("string")

Comment: And please a document that must be found with this query.

Comment: Its empty, that's the issue. The query runs but it is empty. Worth noting the query runs fine on studio3t's Visual Query Builder.

Comment: Why don't you understand that I'm asking for a document in your collection, not that returned by your query (I understand that it is empty)?

Comment: I'm not providing any more information after this as at this point your asking for things you can easily extrapolate. given the fields i want to search are there but here is a document as you requested please attempt to provide an answer, i have not yet tested the current answer provided below.

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "stringofstuffihaveremoved"
    },
    "username": "quickstream",
    "password": "bcrypt hash",
    "firstName": "Matt",
    "surname": "Farrell",
    "email": "email@gmail.com",
    "company": "Home"
}

Comment: here is the query that works, note the word search is just a string and can be replaced with anything.      { "username": { $ne: "quickstream" }, $and: [ { $or: [ { "company": /.*search.*/i }, { "email": /.*search.*/i }, { "firstName": /.*search.*/i }, { "surname": /.*search.*/i }, { "username": /.*search.*/i } ] } ] }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings with slashes won't be interpreted as delimiting regular expressions like you're expecting here. You need to either use the [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex) operator or use Python regular expression objects. You also don't need to use `$and` here as all terms are implicitly "anded".

```
myQuery = {'username' : {'$ne' : session['username']},
           '$or' : [
                 {'username' : {'$regex' : search, '$options': 'i'}},
                 {'surname' : {'$regex' : search, '$options': 'i'}},
                 {'firstName' : {'$regex' : search, '$options': 'i'}},
                 {'email' : {'$regex' : search, '$options': 'i'}},
                 {'company' : {'$regex' : search, '$options': 'i'}}]}
```

Comment: I'll try tomorrow,  thank you for straight answer too rather than asking for pointless information.

Comment: it works, the issue was i forgot i cleared the database so a couple of names i was looking for were not in it no more.